# How to use scan codes to shut down PC?

Tags: c++, keyboard, arduino, shutdown, scancodes

Someone asked me to shut down Windows with a Teensy 2.0. I have to use the following scancodes found on [win.tue.nl](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html).

```
         Set-1 make/brake     Set-2 make/brake
Power    e0 5e / e0 de        e0 37 / e0 f0 37
Sleep    e0 5f / e0 df        e0 3f / e0 f0 3f
Wake     e0 63 / e0 e3        e0 5e / e0 f0 5e
```

Right now I am using Arduino IDE with Teensyduino add-on to program the Teensy. My question is how to use the above called scancodes to simulate a "power" keystroke to shut down a PC?

I hope someone can help me.

/Zwilk

Answer (score 0):

You can find the definitions in [USB Keyboard Library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_keyboard.html) (usb_keyboard.h, usb_keyboard.c) from pjrc. If you want to extend custom keys you can adapt these files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In the USB Keyboard Library I add the Power/Sleep/Wake button. But it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I call it. Can you be more specified about how to do it?